# Query status of service on Linux machine from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linux

I'm trying to query whether a service is running via a SQL job. I know how to check the service of a service on a windows machine, but not a Linux machine.

The SQL Server OS is windows. The server the service is on is Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is unclear. First, define `service on Linux` - there's no single service/daemon mechanism. There's `systemd`, `upstart` and many others. You can run daemons as background jobs without a specific service manager. Whatever mechanism you use, you need to use its tools to determine the status of the daemon/service/process. Some of these may be accessible remotely, some may require SSH, some may have a web interface. And then, there are containers, which are also different

Comment: Which service do you want to monitor? It may have a healthcheck endpoint you can hit. If the services run inside containers they probably expose health endpoints to Docker already. Also, which SQL Server version? All versions in mainstream support can run Python scripts through `sp_execute_external_script`. There may be a Python module that returns the status you want. Even if you don't to call Python from SQL, you can run a Python script as an external job

Comment: Why do you want to do this in SQL?